# Use ajax to render a view - pagination not working

Tags: views, ajax

I'm trying to render a view using Ajax, but I can't get the ajax pagination to work. I've found the following code which works, apart from the pagination:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: '/views/ajax',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    view_name: 'stores',
                    view_display_id: 'default',
                    view_args: {},
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response[1] !== undefined) {
                        $('.store-locator-view-wrap').html(response[1].data);
                        Drupal.attachBehaviors(); // Thought this would do it, but nope
                    }
                }
            });
```

The links go to /views/ajax?page=1 with the following json:

```
[{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"rhm_starter","theme_token":"dRce3KwWhWs1ZpnNe6KVUu31mLX8pdVoZ5XixJo8SVI"}},"merge":true}]
::1
```

Comment: Trying to do the exact same thing and running into the same problem. Noticed that my `Drupal.settings` does not contain a `views` key. Have not discovered anything more past that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the `Drupal.settings` does not have the proper `views` key it needs to attach the behaviors if you are loading a view via `views/ajax`.

There is no good documentation on this, spend alot of time trying to figure it out, but this ended up working. I had to set the `views` key in the settings manually:

```
success: function (response) {
    if (response[1] !== undefined) {
        $('.store-locator-view-wrap').html(response[1].data);

        // Set views key based on response data. 
        Drupal.settings.views = response[0].settings.views;
        Drupal.attachBehaviors();
    }
}
```

I also had to make sure the Views js files had been added to my page:

```
$views_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'views');
drupal_add_js(
    $views_path . '/js/base.js',
    array(
        'type' => 'file',
        'scope' => 'footer',
        'group' => JS_DEFAULT,
    )
);
drupal_add_js(
    $views_path . '/js/ajax_view.js',
    array(
        'type' => 'file',
        'scope' => 'footer',
        'group' => JS_DEFAULT,
    )
);
```

Comment: Looks good, thanks for the response! I could never get it to work this way so I built it a different way.

Comment: Even better, you could probably just do `Drupal.settings = response[0].settings;`

Comment: Actually I'm just trying this now, and it's not working for me. response[0].settings.views returns undefined and if I try Drupal.settings = response[0].settings I just get the same response as it my original question. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually forget that, it works! I had disabled ajax in the view :)

Comment: Haha that was the first thing I was going to ask. Glad it's working out for you.

Comment: I have a bonus question for you, as you've been so helpful! Any idea how to pass the language into the ajax call? At the moment it's returning the default language.

Comment: I have never done localization in Drupal, but I would assume that there was a locale param to pass to the view, much like a contextual filter. I notice there is also a `Drupal.locale` key in the Drupal object, but I'm not sure what it's used for since I never have to add i18n modules.

Comment: I figured it out myself in the end, just need to add it to the front of the ajax call, only if it's not the default language like: url: '/' + lang + '/views/ajax',

Comment: Sweet! That's even easier!

Comment: Excellent!. You saved me :) I tried so many ways to get it work. Finally it's done